# Installing Ispell on OSX

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-yosemite, ispell

I downloaded the ispell tarball from a GNU mirror and am installing Ispell on my OSX. When I do "make all" in my folder, I am getting the following error:

```
[pradeep@laptop ispell-3.1]$make all
+ cc -O -c buildhash.c
In file included from buildhash.c:69:
./config.h:878:1: error: expected identifier or '('
<U+001B>[01;31m<U+001B>[K#define SIGNAL_TYPE_STRING "<U+001B>[m<U+001B>[K void"
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [buildhash.o] Error 1
```

My OS is Yosemite. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not necessary to install either `ispell.el` or `flyspell.el`, because they both come packaged with most installations of Emacs.  They are `elisp` files that do not need to built -- Emacs is designed to read `elisp` files such as `ispell.el` and/or `flyspell.el`.

Instead, what needs to be installed is a third-party executable such as `aspell` or `hunspell`.  The language dictionaries will *also* need to be installed after the main executable is installed.

Essentially, `ispell.el` and `flyspell.el` (with help from Emacs) are **front-ends** for `aspell` or `hunspell`.

---

**NOTE**:  OSX ships with an older version of Emacs.  Instead of using an older version (e.g., `/usr/bin/emacs`), consider using a current version built `--with-ns`:  http://emacsformacosx.com/  For more information on different builds that are available for OSX, the following link has some informative write-ups:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/what-is-the-difference-between-aquamacs-and-other-mac-versions-of-emacs